# How do I loop number counter after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to get the following number counter to start only once scrolled to and then have it loop after 10 seconds, could anyone please assist me

```js
const counterAnim = (qSelector, start = 0, end, duration = 8000) => {
 const target = document.querySelector(qSelector);
 let startTimestamp = null;
 const step = (timestamp) => {
  if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
  const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
  target.innerText = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
  if (progress < 1) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
 };
 window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
};
//#endregion - end of - number counter animation

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
 counterAnim("#count1", 0, 10000,8000);
 counterAnim("#count2", 0, 40, 8000);
 counterAnim("#count3", 0, 5, 8000);
});
```

```html
<div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
<h2 class="title"><span id="count1" class="display-4"></span>+  </h2>
<p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
<h2 class="title"><span id="count2" class="display-4"></span>+  YEARS</h2>
<p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="ohio-heading-sc heading text-left" id="ohio-custom-61aa36a52809a">
<h2 class="title"><span id="count3" class="display-4"></span>   YEAR</h2>
<p class="subtitle">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? Also, how is this related to Wordpress?

Comment: The code works fine, I just need it to run once the div is scrolled to and then refresh after 10 seconds. I'm using the code on a Wordpress website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have most of the setup, you just need to attach your first `counterAnim` calls to a scroll listener and then also start a timeout to reset `startTimestamp` to null after 10 seconds

```
let startTimestamp = null;

const counterAnim = (qSelector, start = 0, end, duration = 8000) => {
 const target = document.querySelector(qSelector);
 const step = (timestamp) => {
  if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
  const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
  target.innerText = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
  if (progress < 1) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
 };

 // reset to the start condition. If you want this to happen multiple times, use setInterval
 setTimeout(() => {
   startTimestamp = null;
 }, 10000);

 window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
};

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
 counterAnim("#count1", 0, 10000,8000);
 counterAnim("#count2", 0, 40, 8000);
 counterAnim("#count3", 0, 5, 8000);
}
```